# Blitting several textures at once with glBlitFramebuffer

Tags: opengl, 3d, pyopengl, fbo

I have got a small OpenGL app and I am looking for the optimal way of blitting several texture buffers at once.

Let's say I have got two framebuffers (`fbo1`, `fbo2`) that each contain two texture buffers. And I have got a target fbo (`fbo3`) with four texture buffers. And I want to blit all the textures from `fbo1` and `fbo2` to `fbo3`.

Currently I am doing it separately for each texture like,

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo1)
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo3)
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)

glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, ds_width, ds_height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR)

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
```

How is it usually done? And is that even doable?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't "usually" done because people generally don't go around copying a bunch of framebuffer images a lot. Indeed, if you are, that strongly suggests that you're probably doing something wrong.

The only way to do it is the way you've done here (though the needless rebinding of the framebuffers can go away): change the read/draw buffers each time and blit.